# Spring MVC: Show data in a dialog after making an AJAX call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I am new to Spring and web technology.

I have an table which contains a column with hyperlink. When I click on the hyperlink of a row, I need to display that rows data along with other details in a dialog. My controller method returns a `ModelAndView` which contains the data I need to show and the display page.

**Problems:**

1. How to show the dialog? and
2. How to pass the data to the dialog?

**Table.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showDialog(ref, date) {

        $ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/example/show.htm",
            data: {
                ref: ref,
                date: date
            }
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        });
}
</script>
```

**Mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "show.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView show(@RequestParam("ref") String ref, @RequestParam("date") String date, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        try {
            SampleDTO SampleDTO = new SampleDTO();
            sampleDTO.setDate(sdf.parse(date));
            sampleDTO.setRef(ref);

            SampleDTO billDto =  // server call                    modelAndView.addObject("showBill", sampleDto);

            modelAndView.setViewName("Dialog");
        } 
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of dialog is that, are you using some modal dialog? because it seems like a `html` page, if you need to use `ajax` then a modal dialog will be good to use instead of a page.

Comment: Okay let me try using a model dialog.

Comment: @OscarJara I have updated the code. Pls tell me how to pass the data to the dialog and show the dialog after returning from the Controller.

Comment: It is not as simple as you did, check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is wrong, you are messing things, if you want to use `jQuery` and `ajax` calls then don't use `ModelAndView` in your `Spring` controller. Instead of that, use the following and `return` your `bean` or `dto` as a `json` using `Jackson` library from `Java`:

**Include this `jar` in your `lib` project folder:**

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jackson/jackson-all-1.9.9.jar.zip

**Java code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "businessBill.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleBusinessBillDetails(@RequestParam("reference") String billReference, @RequestParam("invoiceDate") String billDate, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String json = null;        

    try {

        //1. Create 'jackson' object mapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  

        BusinessBillDTO businessBillDTO = new BusinessBillDTO();
        businessBillDTO.setBillDate(sdf.parse(billDate));
        businessBillDTO.setBillReference(billReference);

        BusinessBillDTO billDto = accountStatementBO.getBusinessBillDetails(businessBillDTO);

        //2. Convert your 'bean' or 'dto' as 'json' string
        json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(billDto);            

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex);
    }
    return json;
}
```

Then, in `Table.jsp` put the `div` used in `Dialog.jsp` as `hidden`, this will be your `modal` dialog in future (note that there are some changes in the `span` tags also):

```
<div id="BusinessBill" style="display:none;">
    <h2>Bill Details</h2>
    <em>Business Ltd</em>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="spanAsLabel">Account number</span>
        <span id="dlg-account-number" class="spanAsLabel"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="spanAsLabel">Bill date</span>
        <span id="dlg-bill-date" class="spanAsLabel"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now fix your `getBusinessBill(..)` method like this:

*You can also use `$.ajax` and maybe handle more states like `onerror` and others but this way is simpler (at least for me, you just need to evaluate if the returned `data` is `null` or not and let know the `user` - **if `null`** - that something happened at `server` side, maybe showing an `alert` with a generic message) - please read comments.*

```
function getBusinessBill(billReference, billInvoiceDate) {

    $.post("/AccountStatement/businessBill.htm", {
        reference: billReference,
        invoiceDate: billInvoiceDate
    }, function (data) {

        /* You can implement more validations for 'data', in my case I just used these 'if' conditionals but can vary. */

        if(data != null) { //returned 'data' is not 'null'

            /* parse 'data' as 'json' object
             * will be good to console.log(data) and take a look. */
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            if(obj != {}) { //check if 'data' is not an empty 'json' object once transformed

               //set the 'data' in the dialog
               $('#dlg-account-number').text(obj.accountNumber);
               $('#dlg-bill-date').text(obj.billDate);

               /* open modal dialog, you can simulate it this way (for this case)
                * but the correct way is to use 'jquery-ui' dialog or any plugin you prefer.
                * At this point you will see the hidden 'div' in a visible way with your 'data'.
                */
               $('#BusinessBill').fadeIn();
            } else {
               //show 'generic' message
               alert('No results found.');
            }
        } else {
           //show 'generic' message
           alert('An error occurred, try again.');
        }
    });

}
```

Finally, if everything is correct, you will see at the same page (`Table.jsp`) the `modal` dialog with your `data`, all made by an `ajax` call to avoid redirection pages like (`Table.jsp` to => `Dialog.jsp`).

Comment: +1. Can u tell me what is 'data' in function (data) {}. B'coz there is nothing like data defined. Sorry I am new to these technologies.

Comment: @Che `data` is just the parameter used to express what is contained in the `callback` from `Spring` controller. There is no need to `declare` it.

Comment: It worked. I have just one more question. So when should I use `ModelAndView`. B'çoz in this case I no need to redirect as I no need to redirect. Is it that `ModelAndView` is used when we need to redirect dynamically to different pages?

Comment: Use `ModelAndView` if you will not use `jQuery` (e.g. like passing parameters from page to page or obtaining data for navigation from the `controller` to the user for an specific page). But, if you want something dynamic or just bring some `data` to client side, do the way I exposed here.